# Finite sum of $_{1}F_{2}$ hypergeometric functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function

Could you help me with this finite sum?

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\,_{1}F_{2}\left(\frac{n+1}{2},\frac{1}{2}+n-k,\frac{1}{2}+k,z\right),
$$

where $_{1}F_{2}$ is a hypergeometric function?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to get from this sum exactly? Do you want to simplify it? Do you want asymptotic behavior? Do you want a closed-form formula? Also do you know things about $z$?

Comment: Yes, a simpler or a closed-form formula! $z$ is a positive real number.

Answer (score 0):

you can simplify it by substituting factorials for the binomial coefficient, expanding the 1F2 function into its own sum resulting in a double summation. you can then follow that with Bailey's transform to reduce the resultant ratio of Pochhammers. I admit that some one may have an easier way to do it. see for example:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274711772_New_summations_of_Neumann_series_of_modified_Bessel_functions